# How do I get urql graphql data in another component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, urql

I have code like this in my `__layout.svelte` file

```html
    const store = operationStore(QUERY_CURRENT_USER);
    query(store);
```

and I can successfully use it like this in that same component like this

```html
    $store.data.firstName
```

**My problem is that I cannot work out a way to access this graphql data in other components within my app.** I can add the query code (first block) again but that doesn't feel like the best way of doing it and ties each component that uses some of that data with that particular query.

I am using SvelteKit and `@urql/svelte`.

Comment: There are several ways to go about this, depending on what your intent is. For example if the data you're querying is not updated frequently, you could simply put it in a Svelte store and access that store somewhere else in your app. If your intent is to query your server again & again (for a resource that updates very often), then yes, you will have to copy that query code wherever you want to use it, or alternatively turn that query into a wrapper component that you can reuse at will (a bit like the React High-order Component model).

Comment: For your use case (current user), I don't think you would need to query the graphql server over & over. Once when a user initially authenticates, where you could store all the user info in a store (or in a session, which is a store in its own way). And eventually refresh that data whenever the user updates his/her info (but imo that would be a different query), and finally you could simply zero out the stored data when the user disconnects. Like I said, how you approach that type of problem is very dependent on the use case.